# Difficulty overriding windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, windows-authentication, iis-express

I have been scouring the internet to try and solve this. I've looked at many question on here, used MSDN and asp.net websites++

I have a website, code first database. I am also using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`. Everything in the website is published and deployed, except, I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an
>   untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

I've tried multiple things in my webconfig.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    // Removing, setting enable= false in here, lots of things ++
</system.webServer>
```

and my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"   
    connectionString="Data Source= xxxxxt;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User 
    Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;  
    Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=True;  
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

I have altered my IISExpress -> config -> applicationhost.config

```
 <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Even though there are local paths with overrides allowed in the iisexpress configs, I haven't been able to get them to work in the webconfig.

The last thing I have been doing is trying to work out how to override any inbuilt windows authentication that may be in the inbuilt identity framework, and I just can't find the answer.

Any help is appreciated.

---

I have edited my connection string as suggested by

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    connectionString="Data Source=xxx;integrated security=false;Initial Catalog=xxx;
    User Id=xxx;xxx; Trusted_Connection=false;TrustServerCertificate=false;
    Encrypt=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

And I now get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE permission denied
>   in database 'master'

At least that's a new problem I can work on.

Comment: is sqlserver on the same machine? if not are you allowing remote connections? are you using TCP or Named Pipes within your sqlServer?

Comment: Using username and password set "Trusted_Connection=false;"

Comment: Read this site for best practices.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998292.aspx

Comment: did you set the username and password in the database and set the users  default database, and user mappings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for new issue.

Hey here are your connection strings.

Standard Security

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

SQL Server 2000SQL Server 2005SQL Server 2008SQL Server 2012SQL Server 7.0

Trusted Connection

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

SQL Server 2000SQL Server 2005SQL Server 2008SQL Server 2012SQL Server 7.0

Connection to a SQL Server instance
The server/instance name syntax used in the server option is the same for all

SQL Server connection strings.

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: Im glad you have it working now and glad i could help